# How to edit images using entitySource or linq

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I can easily insert image but unable to edit them.

Table:

```
TableName
D_Image
column = 
ImageID int (Prmry key)
PhotoName nvarchar(256)
Photo nvarchar(256)
```

My Edit template:

```
<asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
<asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
<asp:TextBox ID="PhotoNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.PhotoName %>' />

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
      ImageUrl='<%# BindItem.Photo %>' Width="135" />

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

CODE BEHIND IS

```
Protected Sub EntityDataSource1_Updating(sender As Object, e As EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs) Handles EntityDataSource1.Updating
    Dim ImageID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("ImageID") )
    Dim D_Image As D_Image = CType(e.Entity, D_Image)
    Dim FileUpload1 As FileUpload = CType(Listview1.InsertItem.FindControl("FileUpload 1"), FileUpload)
    Dim VirtualFolder As String = "~/Pics1/"
    Dim PhysicalFolder As String = Server.MapPath(VirtualFolder)
    Dim Extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)
    Dim filename As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
    Dim Path As String = VirtualFolder + filename + Extension
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Physical Folder, filename + Extension))
    D_Image.Photo = Path.ToString
    Label1.Text = D_Image.Photo
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing `D_Image` is the entity class? If so, where are you saving the record? You also should change the name of the instance so it's not the same as the class.

Comment: yes D_Image is the entity class... and i am trying to save the record in `D_Image.photo=path.tostring`  i am unable to update the image or unable to replace the existing one. seriously need help..

Comment: That code does not *save* the image to the database. It simply changes the data on that in-memory instance in your program. You need to reattach that entity to your context in your data source and save it. Also; please take a look in the [Help] for [how to do formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: can you send me that to save the to the database?